# What are the two subtrees for C that makes it unbalanced?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, tree-balancing

In the tree:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C <-- Difference = 2
 /   /
D   E
   /
  G
```

What are the two subtrees for node C that make it unbalanced??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's solve some homework Leslie...

The C tree has two subtrees.  One of them isn't pictured...

```
     C
   /   \
  E
 /
G
```

Calculate the height of each subtree.  Height 2 vs Height 0...

Comment: Hi Ryan! Thanks for your response!

Comment: Then from what you said. That means for leaf nodes, they also have two subtrees, right? They have two nullptr for their left and right children right? I guess I just forgot that nullptr can be used as subtrees! Could you confirm what I said above was true?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tree is a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), each node in such tree has at max 2 nodes. While representing a tree if a child node is not explicitly drawn or mentioned, it is assumed to be `null`.

Thus the node `C` in your case has only one child node i.e. `E` and the other child is null.